# Render Reddit embed into ReactJs Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, embed, reddit

I am unable to render properly the reddit embed for a post, for some reason, when the iframe generates, the height gets cut off. If I manually select the iframe from developer tools, and uncheck "height: auto" it resizes properly. I have no idea how to fix this or what might be causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class RedditEmbedComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    renderFrame = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <blockquote class="reddit-card" data-card-created="1553892582">
                    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/b6wjlb/a_billion_people_may_be_newly_exposed_to_diseases/">
                        A billion people may be newly exposed to diseases like dengue fever as world temperature rises by the end of the century because of global
                warming, says a new study that examines temperature changes on a monthly basis across the world.</a> from
                <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/science">r/science</a></blockquote>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            {this.renderFrame()}
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks ok here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0myzzo1wjv -- Does this sandbox reflect your issue?

Comment: @wdm hmm it doesn't, I am using bulma underneath, maybe it is possible that is causing the issue then :(